How to Calculate checksum for xbee in AT mode
i do some reverse engineering with xbee transmitter in AT mode. its transmission data are as below. Plese help me to understand how its checksum is calculated. I hope last number is the checksum, if that number changed, receiver does not response.
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x07 0x00 0x0e 0x3a
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x09 0x00 0x0a 0x5a
0x7e 0x01 0x14 0x36 0x00 0x5a 0x52
0x7e 0x09 0x31 0x28 0x00 0x40 0x59
I tryed adding all bytes except 0x7e then 0xFF - value of all bytes sum. It doesnot work.

How did you acquire this data?  It seems to be three separate packets run together (since XBee's frame delimiter is 0x7E), but none of them are valid - their length fields are all nonsense.  (Official documentation on XBee checksums can be found at https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/Digidocs/90002002/Content/Tasks/t_calculate_checksum.htm?TocPath=API%20Operation%7CAPI%20frame%20format%7C_____1, but that's not going to do you any good until you manage to get a complete data capture.)

Thank you for your early reply. This is not standard  packet type. I got this data through oscilloscope. What are the values in packet are correct. It is a custom data packet without length field.  I have given four data samples. Each sample contain 07  bytes. 1st and 4th are fixed  for all the  packets .

Some more data packets              0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x0c 0xfa
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x0e 0xca
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x05 0x00 0x0f 0x5a
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x0f 0xaa
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x07 0x00 0x0e 0x3a
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x08 0x00 0x0b 0xca
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x09 0x00 0x0a 0x5a
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 0xca
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x5a
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x12 0x00 0x00 0xaa
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x13 0x00 0x01 0x3a
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x03 0x0a

An XBee radio in AT mode (ATAP=0) passes serial data transparently.
An XBee radio in API mode (ATAP=1) sends packetized data with a start frame byte (0x7E), length bytes and frame type.  You can read about the frame format in Digi's XBee documentation -- no reverse engineering necessary.

Sir, this eqipment is not using any standard data format. It is a custom format. If i modify a number, then receiver dosnot responce    0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x0c 0xfa
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x0e 0xca
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x05 0x00 0x0f 0x5a
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x0f 0xaa
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x07 0x00 0x0e 0x3a
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x08 0x00 0x0b 0xca
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x09 0x00 0x0a 0x5a
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 0xca
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x5a
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x12 0x00 0x00 0xaa
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x13 0x00 0x01 0x3a
0x7e 0x00 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x03 0x0a

Those aren't XBee API packets.  It's some other protocol unrelated to the XBee, but sharing a possible pattern of packets starting with 0x7E.  My recommendation would be to continue capturing packets and putting them into a sorted list so you can just stare at it looking for patterns.
The sequence of the 4th byte going from 0x09 to 0x10 seems like it could be BCD (binary-coded decimal) encoding.  You could also group packets by the final byte to look for patterns in the previous bytes.  Interesting that the last nibble is always 0xA.  Make sure you're decoding the serial stream correctly.

Thank you for spending your valuable time.  Actually sir this is not API packet type. It is in AT mode whitch transmit row data. In that pattern 2nd to  4th bytes are HH:MM:SS respectively. 1st and 5th are constant. 6th & 7th are unknown. I am trying to understand those two bytes. Serial data is correct. If i transmit same data receiver response and changing any of them receiver doesnot response. That is why i am thinking last two bytes contain some kind of checksum value.
